# Laravel filesystem sftp set umask for new folders

Tags: laravel, filesystems, sftp, umask

is it possible to set a *umask* for new created folders

```
Storage::disk('sftp')->put('/path/to/folder/new/test.txt', $contents);
```

In my case, the used *umask* is 744. Is it possible to change the *umask* for new created folders?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was enough to set `directoryPerm` with the needed umask in the config of the `sftpAdapter`

Comment: Cool. Just posted an answer, but didn't realized you found it. Normally when you find a solution, or someone post a solution, you should accept it as answer, so other people can see it easily to avoid losing much time. In my case, if you had accepted your answer, you would have saved me a full day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function :

```
File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, true, true);
```

In your case, just change the $mode to 0774 :

```
Storage::disk('sftp')->makeDirectory($path, 0774);
```

Documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem#introduction

Comment: Unfortunately not. This will create a folder with 0774. I need 0775 and 0775 don´t work

Comment: Try to replace 0774 by 0775

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the `'directoryPerm' => 0755,` key value in config. The config:

```
'disks' => [
    'remote-sftp' => [
        'driver' => 'sftp',
        'host' => '222.222.222.222',
        'port' => 22,
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'password',
        'visibility' => 'public', // set to public to use permPublic, or private to use permPrivate
        'permPublic' => 0755, // whatever you want the public permission is, avoid 0777
        'root' => '/path/to/web/directory',
        'timeout' => 30,
        'directoryPerm' => 0755, // whatever you want
    ],
],
```

And in the codes, class `League\Flysystem\Sftp\StfpAdapter` in file `/private/var/www/megalobiz/vendor/league/flysystem-sftp/src/StfpAdapter` , there is 2 important attributes to see clearly:

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $configurable = ['host', 'hostFingerprint', 'port', 'username', 'password', 'useAgent', 'agent', 'timeout', 'root', 'privateKey', 'passphrase', 'permPrivate', 'permPublic', 'directoryPerm', 'NetSftpConnection'];

/**
 * @var int
 */
protected $directoryPerm = 0744;
```

The `$configurable` is all possible keys to configure filesystem sftp driver above. You can change `directoryPerm` from `0744` to `0755` in config file:

```
'directoryPerm' => 0755,
```

HOWEVER, because there is kind a like a Bug in StfpAdapter https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-sftp/issues/81 that won't use the $config parameter on `createDir`:

```
$filesystem = Storage::disk('remote-sftp');
$filesystem->getDriver()->getAdapter()->setDirectoryPerm(0755);
$filesystem->put('dir1/dir2/'.$filename, $contents);
```

Or set it with public in purpose:

```
$filesystem->put('dir1/dir2/'.$filename, $contents, 'public');
```